# Why is Excel VBA overwriting these object values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a list of objects in VBA but it seems like new objects are not being created and values are being updated to a single instance of a class.

This is the class

```
' ---------------------------------------------------------------
'
' Class to represent Program Increment
'
' ---------------------------------------------------------------

Public name As String

Public sprints As New Collection
```

This is the calling code:

```
' get the unique pi values
Dim piList As New Collection
For r = firstRow To lastRow
    currentVal = Cells(r, 2)
    On Error Resume Next
        Dim currentPi As New ProgramIncrement
        currentPi.name = currentVal
        piList.Add currentPi, currentVal
    On Error GoTo 0
Next
```

This is the output for the first pi 
[image]

And this is the output for the second pi
[image]

I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong base upon online documents such as this.
https://analystcave.com/vba-vba-class-tutorial/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`As New` creates an auto-instantiated object. `Dim` statements aren't executable, so there's only one object indeed.

Remove `As New` and use `Set ... = New` statements to create new objects.

```
Dim currentPi As ProgramIncrement
Set currentPi = New ProgramIncrement
```

`Dim` being inside the loop makes no difference - on one hand it makes it easy to later refactor and extract the loop body into its own procedure scope; on the other hand it *can* be read as though a new variable is created at every iteration, but that's not how scopes work in VBA: the smallest scope is procedure scope - blocks (e.g. loop bodies) don't scope anything.

Answer (score -1):

This worked per Mathieu Guindon's answer.

```
Dim piList As New Collection
Dim currentPi As ProgramIncrement
For r = firstRow To lastRow
    currentVal = Cells(r, 2)
    Set currentPi = New ProgramIncrement
    currentPi.name = currentVal
    On Error Resume Next
        piList.Add currentPi, currentVal
    On Error GoTo 0
Next
```

Comment: Edited to reflect this.